# removing the link in the listings title

Tags: navigation

I have removed the title node module element from my listings and replaced it with a text field.  The problem is that the text field still works as a link.  How do I get rid of the link?

Comment: I have no clue what module you're referring to. Can you link to the module in question?

Comment: Hi, Shawn.  OK, I had a content type of "listing." There is a "title" field which has the field type as "node module element" which is automatically automatically created as a field by drupal and this field, the title, links to a page displaying the full content.  I had to remove this automatic linking.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn.  OK, I had a content type of "listing." There is a "title" field which has the field type as "node module element" which is automatically created as a field by the view for this page.  This field, the title, links to a page displaying the full content.  I had to remove this automatic linking. I downloaded a couple of modules to hide the title, and created a new text field to replace the title field, strange enough, this was also converted into linkable text. I then edited "node.tpl.php" to remove the